# Integral of function on mapped set with reduced dimension

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-integral

A question from a dumb phycisist. I found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2436463/can-integrals-of-higher-dimension-be-reduced-to-1d-integrals-by-space-filling-cu) similar question but it is about space filling curves, not bijective maps.

I understand the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/427664/bijective-measurable-map-existence) as: there are always bijective measurable maps between $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$ for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Consider a friendly function

$\displaystyle f\colon \ \mathbb{R}^2\to Z, \ (x_1,x_2)\mapsto z=f(x_1,x_2)$.

Riemann integrals

$\displaystyle I(a_1,a_2,b_1,b_2) = \int_{a_1}^{a_2}dx_1\int_{b_1}^{b_2} dx_2 \ f(x_1,x_2)$

shall exist for the function. Now the bijective measurable map $m$ comes into play.

$\displaystyle m\colon \ \mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}, \ (x_1,x_2)\mapsto x=m(x_1,x_2)$.

We use it to define another function $\tilde{f}(x) \equiv f(x_1,x_2)$ depending only on 1 variable $x$.

**Is it possible, to define an integral $J$ for $\tilde{f}(x)$ that has the same values as the Riemann integral $I$**?

I.e.

$\displaystyle J(\Omega) = \int_\Omega \tilde{f}(x)\ d\mu(x) = I(a_1,a_2,b_1,b_2)$

with $\Omega$ beeing the image set, i.e. $[a_1,a_2]\times[b_1,b_2]\to \Omega$.

And if yes, **which type of integral is sufficient to do the job**?